# Design Recommendation..DB View with Entity Framework vs Regular Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing an application .NET MVC 5.. which pulls user information from database (SQL Server)..User can search for employees based on first name , last name or any other parameter (5 such parameters).

I looking for a design recommendation, is it preferable to develop a database view which has all the employees information (and use Entity Framework to connect to database) and filter data on the front end (say employee view can be accessed in MVC using DBContext and filer on view)

or

Develop a stored procedure which takes these parameters from front end and return a result set that I use.

My doubt is, when I access database view using entity framework and filter data, does it have performance impact (because view has Million records).

Is it passing a filtered query to the database or accessing the initial object which has million records is a performance hit

Answer (score 0):

Easy as pie: *Always* stored procedure. *Never* database view.

Database views are not keyed and not indexed, which means they are very slow to query.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the recommendation..Can u also address this..use  Entity framework and filter view   or    stored procedure for every hit from front end..The advantage with view is it has all the information and I can filter data on the front end where as stored procedure I always have to send parameters to database..

Comment: Again, that's exactly what you *don't* want to use a view for. If you use a view, it should be returning *exactly* the data you need. If you need to filter it at all, views are completely out the window. Either use the database table directly or use a stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you..I got it..Would it be still ok to hit a stored procedure without entity framework and read using data-reader into a modal..

Comment: Well, you *could*, but that's that's not really the optimal way to go about it. You'd be better off just adding methods to your context that execute your stored procedures and return enumerables of strongly-typed objects.

Comment: Entity framework does the same thing internally right..I mean I am not doing anything else just hitting one stored procedure..Thats all is app about..